Short story about a boy trapped on a planet with an alien criminal who can go into his mind
I read this sci-fi story when I was a kid, and don’t remember the title or author anymore. What I vaguely remember is that a young boy gets trapped (stranded?) on a planet during a school trip and comes across an alien. I think that the alien was exiled there as punishment for a crime, but that might not be right.
The alien tells the kid he can never actually go home (I think the alien says he’s lonely and won’t let him leave) but the alien said it can go into his mind and make him think he’s home.
The end of the story is that the kid “wakes up” in his bed, everything is so real, he can hear his mom calling from downstairs and smell breakfast. In reality, he’s comatose and stranded forever on the planet with the alien in his mind.

Welcome to SciFi.SE. When exactly did you read this? We don't know when you were a kid
